# SSL Insecure content warning in IE and Firefox

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I'm having a real struggle here.  I'm developing a WordPress website, employers.kirkleescollege.ac.uk, but the secure pages are being reported as insecure e.g. https://employers.kirkleescollege.ac.uk/login

I've used the developer tools to look at the network activity.  I can see no references to http, only https.  I can't find any insecure content :(

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me was absolute paths in more than one css files loaded by plugins.  The main culprit being Visual Composer.

In the end, I took these steps to find the problem:

1. In chrome, loaded the web developer tools using F12
2. Went to the network tab
3. Clicked on each loaded css file
4. Searched for 'http' i.e. images with absolute paths
5. Replaced with relative paths

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common behaviour in wordpress. Workaround is dump your database and search for `siteurl` option name in wp_options table. Get that value(Ex: http://www.yourdomain.com). Replace it with `https://www.yourdomain.com` and save the file and import it to the database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is correct, but only if you want you whole site to be loaded over https, and not just specific pages/sections